# How to redirect user to home page if user is authentic i.e ID or PASSWORD is correct in vue.js using VUEX STORE state?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am setting user authenticity in VUEX Store state if user id and password are valid. But how would I access this in my signIn.vue to redirect?

If user is valid then set VUEX store state i.e isUserAuthentic to true
For this I've used computed properties. to get user state i.e isUserAuthentic and work around in hasUserSignedIn in computed properties. I'm checking if user is authentic then redirect and return undefined from this computed properties. So that I can use this in HTML and doesn't affect HTML because I'm returning undefined from that computed properties.
It is working but that's not perfect/best practices.

**SignIn.vue**

```
<template>
    <section>
        <div class="form-wrapper">

            //--------------------------------------USING COMPUTED PROPERTIES
            {{ hasUserSignedIn }}
            
            <input v-model="email"/>
            <input v-model="password"/>

            <button class="btn-signin" @click="submit()">
                sign in
            </button>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  data() {
     email: '',
     password: '',
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {

      if (this.email && this.password) {
        this.$store.dispatch('signInUser', { email: this.email, password: this.password });
      }
    },
    redirectTohome() {
      this.$router.push({ path: '/home' });
    },
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['isUserAuthentic']),

    //-----------------------------------------WORKAROUND COMPUTED PROPERTIES
    hasUserSignedIn() {
      if (this.isUserAuthentic) {
        this.redirectTohome();
      }
      return undefined;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**VUEX signin.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

// const URL = 'http://localhost:3000';

const state = {
  signInLoading: false,
  isUserAuthentic: false,
};

const getters = {
  isSignInLoading: (signInState) => signInState.signInLoading,
  isUserAuthentic: (signInState) => signInState.isUserAuthentic,
};

const mutations = {
  SET_SIGNIN_LOADING_STATUS(signInState, status) {
    signInState.signInLoading = status;
  },
  SET_USER_AUTHENTICITY(signInState, isAuthentic) {
    signInState.isUserAuthentic = isAuthentic;
  },
};

const actions = {
  async signInUser({ commit }, payload) {
    // SET LOADING STATUS TRUE
    commit('SET_SIGNIN_LOADING_STATUS', true);

    try {
      // AUTHORIZE USER WITH AXIOS
      const response = await axios.post(`${URL}/api/v1/user/signin`, payload);

      // IF USER IS AUTHENTIC, SET AUTHENTIC STATUS TO TRUE
      if (response.status === 200) {
        commit('SET_USER_AUTHENTICITY', true);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // SEND TOAST NOTIFICATION TO USER FOR INVALID REQUESTS
      if (e.response && e.response.data.message) {
        Vue.$toast(e.response.data.message, {
          type: 'info',
          timeout: 8000,
        });
      } else {
        Vue.$toast('Something went wrong, Please try again.', {
          type: 'error',
          timeout: 8000,
        });
      }
    }

    // SET LOADING STATUS FALSE
    commit('SET_SIGNIN_LOADING_STATUS', false);
  },
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the docs and I think **WATCHERS** are much better than **COMPUTED** in this particular case.

In this approach we don't have to use {{ hasUserSignedIn }} in HTML. Just watch the property and when it is true redirect to home.

```
 watch: {
    isUserAuthentic(val) {
      if (val) {
        this.redirectTohome();
      }
    },
  },
```

**If someone have better solution, You are more than welcome**

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much spot on. The only thing I feel you should do is that you can wait for the promise of the store dispatch('signInUser') to resolve and check the state of `isUserAuthentic`. Something like this:

#### SignIn.vue

```js
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  data() {
     email: '',
     password: '',
  },
  methods: {
    async submit() { // use the 'async' keyword so that you can use await

      if (this.email && this.password) {
        await this.$store.dispatch('signInUser', { email: this.email, password: this.password }); // wait for the signInUser action to complete
        if (this.isUserAuthentic) {
          this.redirectTohome();
        }
      }
    },
    redirectTohome() {
      this.$router.push({ path: '/home' });
    }
},
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['isUserAuthentic']), // mapState will be better here since you don't alter the state
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
...
    {{ isUserAuthentic }}
 ...
</template>
```

Also, as an aside, I feel you should fire a commit i.e `commit('SET_USER_AUTHENTICITY', false);` when there's a failure. That's missing from your code.

Since you are returning the state as is, and not altering it, `mapState` will be better than `mapGetters` in your case.

Comment: thanks tony for helping me. But I think watchers are better. I've suggested my solution. Please see if I'm right.

Comment: The watchers solution will work, @androidOcean. My only problem with it is that if you come back to the code-base in a few months, or if a new developer takes over the project, it's difficult to follow what's happening. The watcher is separate from the `submit` method which actually triggers it.